# How to select the longest token in a ES filter

Tags: elasticsearch

Input is a list of people name, and I want to create an exact match with a little fuzziness.

Index text is Bao-An Feng, My Analyzer is below

```
PUT trim
{
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "analysis": {
        "filter": {
          "word_joiner": {
            "type": "shingle",
            "output_unigrams": false,
            "token_separator": "",
            "output_unigrams_if_no_shingles": true,
            "max_shingle_size": 5
          }
        },
        "analyzer": {
          "word_join_analyzer": {
            "type": "custom",
            "tokenizer": "standard",
            "filter": [
              "lowercase",
              "word_joiner"
            ]
          }
        },
        "tokenizer": {}
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It will generate three token

```
{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": "baoan",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 6,
      "type": "shingle",
      "position": 0
    },
    {
      "token": "baoanfeng",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 11,
      "type": "shingle",
      "position": 0,
      "positionLength": 2
    },
    {
      "token": "anfeng",
      "start_offset": 4,
      "end_offset": 11,
      "type": "shingle",
      "position": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

I only want "baoanfeng", I can not utilize "min_shingle_size", because there can be input with two words.

Comment: Just so i understand completely, you want only the longest token created to be indexed when you create a new document? or are you using the [analyze](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-analyze.html) function and want to limit those results? what about if you got multiple tokens with the same length? whats the desired behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you're using a `shingle` filter if all you need is the longest shingle...

Why not simply a `keyword` tokenizer with a pattern filter that removes everything that is not a character? Like this:

```
PUT trim
{
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "analysis": {
        "filter": {
          "pattern": {
            "type": "pattern_replace",
            "pattern": "\\W+",
            "replacement": ""
          }
        },
        "analyzer": {
          "word_join_analyzer": {
            "type": "custom",
            "tokenizer": "keyword",
            "filter": [
              "lowercase",
              "pattern"
            ]
          }
        },
        "tokenizer": {}
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then test it out:

```
POST trim/_analyze
{
  "analyzer": "word_join_analyzer",
  "text": "Bao-An Feng"
}
```

Results:

```
{
  "tokens" : [
    {
      "token" : "baoanfeng",
      "start_offset" : 0,
      "end_offset" : 12,
      "type" : "word",
      "position" : 0
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks, you are right. Shouldn't use shingle token filter